# Webpack not able to interpret files?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-5

I'm trying to use webpack with react and ts so I can optimise my websites, however I have come to a stumbling point with webpack. Below is my webpack.config.js file, which I believe is all correct, but maybe not? And below that is the image of the error.

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './src/index.tsx'),
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js|\.tsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    mode: 'development',
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './src/index.html'),
        }),
    ],
}
```

[image: error-screenshot]

This is happening to CSS and webp files, but you can only see the CSS in the screenshot.

The file structure is like this:

```
- build
- src
    - App.tsx
    - index.tsx
    - index.html
    - react-app-env.d.ts
    - css
        - animations.css
        - App.css
        - index.css
        - nav.css
    - images
        - hero.webp
        - image1.webp
        - logo.webp
    - webpack
        - webpack.config.js
    - .babel.rc
    - package.json
    - tsconfig.json
    - yarn.lock
```

Hopefully this gives enough info for a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### You are missing loader to handle CSS files.

Just like you have added loader in `module.rules` array to handle `.js` and `.tsx` file, similarly you have to add appropriate file loader to handle `.css` file.

For that you need to install at least two npm packages, **css-loader** and **style-loader**. [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/) reads all CSS files and manages imports, url path, font imports within it. Other the hand [style-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/) fetch CSS from `bundle.js` and put it into DOM as no separate CSS file.

##### install required loaders.

`npm install style-loader css-loader --save-dev`

##### configure installed loader into webpack.

```
module.exports = {
    ...,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js|\.tsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            }
        ],
    },
    ...
}
```

> ##### You can extract CSS and put it separate `.css` file.
>
> As css-loader manages css within files and style-loader helps to put it in dom. If you want separate css file, you need to add plugin for that.

All you need is [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/).

##### install required package

`npm install mini-css-extract-plugin --save-dev`

##### configure install plugin into webpack.

1. Add style-loader provided by `MiniCssExtractPlugin` instead of `style-loader`, change `style-loader` to `MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader`.
2. Add `MiniCssExtractPlugin` to plugins array.

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './src/index.tsx'),
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js|\.tsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            }
        ],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    mode: 'development',
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './src/index.html'),
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
    ],
}
```